# Why can't I update this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have three tables in SQL Server 2008 R2: `Country` `Address` and `Country_Address`

---

`Country` has columns:

`CountryID` `Country`

1, Afghanistan

2, Australia

---

`Address` has columns:

`AddressID` `Address`

1, 5 Smith Way

---

`Country_Address` has columns:

`CountryID` `AddressID`

1, 1

**edit**: so in the example, 5 smith way is an address for Afghanistan.

I have emptied the tables, then added two countries and one address, and then a link in `Country_Address` between 1 and 1. When I try to update the `CountryID` from 1 to 2, I can't because of FK constraint. I don't understand why this is, because the `CountryID` I am trying to assign does exist. So how do I manage to update it?

---

**edit1**: This is the error I get when I try to do the update in SQL Management Studio, I get `InvalidOperationException` - "The model of type '...' could not be updated." in Visual Studio.

> No row was updated.
>
> The data in row 1 was not committed.
> Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data
> Provider. Error Message: The UPDATE
> statement conflicted with the FOREIGN
> KEY constraint
> "FK_Country_Address_Address". The
> conflict occurred in database
> "...", table
> "dbo.Address", column 'AddressID'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are you trying to update the CountryID in "Country_Address" table? Have you checked to make sure you don't have CountryID as a primary key or a constraint on the column? Also, how can an Address belong to more than 1 Country? Why don't you just put the CountryID directly into the Address.

Comment: This has been edited a bit from my real example but the relationship is the same even though it may not make perfect sense in this example. `CountryID` is PK in `Country` table, and FK in `Country_Address` table. Why would a constraint stop the update that I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you try to update the primary key value in the Countries table, the Country_Address table would then contain an invalid reference back to the Countries table.

If you want to update the keys like this, the easiest way is to enable what are called cascading updates. You do this when creating the foreign keys themselves.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28SQL.80%29.aspx

---

**EDIT:** If I'm finally understanding this correctly, I think the foreign keys in `Country_Address` are reversed, or at least incorrect on the `CountryID` column. Please verify the foreign key definitions.

Doing `UPDATE Country_Address SET CountryID = 2` *should* work if everything is set up correctly. The error message you're getting when attempting to update should *never* cause an invalid value in an `AddressID` column -- this indicates to me that the foreign key is set up incorrectly.

Comment: As mentioned, this doesn't address the design issue. But assuming I've identified the right problem, it shows how to correct it.

Comment: But what I am trying to do is not update the PK in Countries table, but rather, change the relationship in `Country_Address`. I know the (design of the) example is not perfect. Essentially what I am doing is say 5 smith way is not an `Address` for Afghanistan but an `Address` for Australia......

Comment: @baron: It should be possible to do that update... could you please edit your question to include the *exact* error message you get?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL server, Tools tab -> Options-> Designer -> unselect the Prevent from making changes option.
Then can directly edit table.
If after adding row data, get error "no row was updated".
Then select "New Query" then write insert query for a particular table. That's it 
It worked for me ,hope it might help